# what does getAssertionResults(); returns and how to check it in bean shell post processor in jmeter

Tags: java, methods, jmeter, assertion, beanshell

I am a beginner as JMeter so, please excuse if I am not able to explain it properly or it is a silly question.

I am checking certain response Text through Response Assertion for HTTP request sampler. ie Text response contains:

`class="panel-pane pane-panels-mini pane-fire-ev-header-top" | id="block-panels_mini-fire_ev_header_top"` etc.

And want to use `prev.getAssertionResults()` in bean shell post processor as condition - i.e if response text contains above mention text than performing certain steps otherwise fails. But not sure what `getAssertionResults()` returns.

How can I do that, please?

Comment: Be aware that PostProcessors are executed **before** any assertions so you won't be able to access Response Assertion results from the Beanshell PostProcessor, consider using Beanshell Assertion instead

Answer (score 1):

The method you are referring returns an array of [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) instances associated with the parent sampler, see the JavaDoc for all available methods and fields. You can use it as follows:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;

AssertionResult[] assertionResults = prev.getAssertionResults();
for (AssertionResult assertionResult : assertionResults) {
    if (assertionResult.isFailure()) {
        // do what you need if assertion is not successful
    } else {
        //do what you need if assertion is successful
    }
}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on using JMeter assertions.

---

NB: you may find [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with condition of `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` easier to use.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri for your answer. When I use above code it give me error msg on log :                                                   jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `` //import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;  String code = prev.getR . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: AssertionResult not found in namespace

Comment: Don't forget the first line: `import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;`, you need to use the [import statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) to load the classes from 3rd-party packages. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more details.

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to guess where is the syntax problem in your code without seeing it. Given your equivocal programming skills the "If Controller" approach will be a better solution

Comment: I imported import org.apache.jmeter.assertionsAssertionResult; , and now I am getting this error message :                jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: `` import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;  //String code = prev.getR . . . '' Encountered "}" at line 15, column 5.